# Show that $\alpha_i$ are integral over $k[x]$ and generate the integral closure over $k[x]$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $2$. Let $f(x) \in k[x]$ be a polynomial of positive degree without double roots in $k$.
Also assume that $k$ is algebraically closed and perfect.
Then $f'(x)$ is a square in $k[x]$.
Write it  $f'(x):=(\prod_{i=1}^{t}(x-b_i)^{r_i})^2.$

I'd like to show that

> The elements
> $$\alpha_i := \frac{\sqrt{f(b_i)}-\sqrt{f(x)}}{(x-b_i)^{r_i}}, \quad i=1, \dots, t,$$
> are integral over $k[x]$

And also

> The set $\{1, \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_t\}$ generates the integral closure $B$ over $k[x]$ in $k(x)(\sqrt{f})$.

Comment: I've thought that algebraically closed fields are perfect.

Comment: Moreover, an irreducible polynomial over k is separable and its derivative doesn't look like you say.

Comment: @user26857 It comes from Lorenzini‘s invitation to arithmetic geometry, example 4.23, 26p.

Comment: The book assumes that $k$ is algebraically closed later than you did.